# Super street fighter 4 Z-shaped move on keyboard?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

How do you do a Z-shaped move on a keyboard? I have tried it on a lot of ways, but I can't find out how. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Down</kbd>, press <kbd>Forward</kbd>, release <kbd>Down</kbd>, then press <kbd>Light Punch</kbd>, <kbd>Medium Punch</kbd>, or <kbd>Fierce Punch</kbd>.
All in one successive motion (for Haduken).

Holding the first direction while pressing the second creates the diagonal input you need.